# How to remove the frame in the Mac Appstore from the application icon?

Tags: macos, app-store, mac-catalyst

There is an ios application that is ported to macos using catalyst. When submit the latest update, the application icon in the MacAppstore has strange borders. At the same time, the application icon in macOS is displayed correctly.

[image]